# pandoc markdown to pdf showing file names next to image

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, markdown, pandoc

When I convert a markdown file to pdf using pandoc, any image links such as

```
![](path/to/name_of_file)
```

the pdf includes the image but has a "Figure n:" under the image. How can I suppress this behaviour?

Secondly, if I include a header using

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{/Users/pdd/Documents/DATA/Work/Logo/DCM logo email image.jpg}}
```

in my template.latex file, the pdf includes the image but displays the image name before the image, inserts a horizontal line under the image and places "Heading 1" on the right of the page as an additional header. Again, how can I suppress this behaviour?

Many Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a filename for the image that does not contain any spaces, the heading disappears. That's the simple and quick solution to this, even if it's not the most satifactory.